# Launch and Attach to NW.JS program from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, nw.js

Does anyone have a launch.json example that will work for Visual Studio Code to attach or launch a NW.JS desktop program. Yes, I know that NW.JS uses chromium debug, and you can debug it directly that way. But it would be nice to be able to debug and single step from VS CODE.

I assume it uses port 9222 (below does not work)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "DOM Debug",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/nw.exe",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
            ],
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "diagnosticLogging": true,
            "port": 9222
        },
        {
            "name": "Node Debug",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/nw.exe",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
            ],
            "url": "chrome-extension://*/_generated_background_page.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "diagnosticLogging": true,
            "port": 9222
        }
    ]
}
```

Attached below is the log:

[Vscode log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8283278/vscode-chrome-debug.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can debug NW.JS applications with a modified Debugger for Chrome extension and the following configurations in my launch.json file.   Note that I have one configuration for debugging the browser context and another for debugging the node context.  I tried mixed mode but the breakpoints were never hit.  This setup assumes the application files and NW.JS executable are in the same directory.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "nwjs DOM debug",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/nw.exe",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
            ],
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "diagnosticLogging": true,
            "port": 9222
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "nwjs Node debug",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/nw.exe",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
            ],
            "url": "chrome-extension://*/_generated_background_page.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "diagnosticLogging": true,
            "port": 9222
        }
    ]
}
```

I modified the Debugger for Chrome extension by changing a function to allow all scripts that are found to be loaded and mapped.  The debugger normally excludes extension:// and chrome-extension:// scripts.

In file *[extensions path]\.vscode\extensions\msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-2.3.2\node_modules\vscode-chrome-debug-core\out\src\chrome\chromeDebugAdapter.js* change function shouldIgnoreScript() to return false.

```js
shouldIgnoreScript(script) {
    return false;//script.url.startsWith('extensions::') || script.url.startsWith('chrome-extension://');
}
```

One side effect is when the debugger starts in the node context you will get a lot messages saying that the debugger can't find the native node modules for NW.JS.  No big deal as long as you weren't needing to step into them.

This setup works for me but it is still flaky and the debugger websocket connection will drop seemingly at random.  But it's been reliable enough to debug without resorting to lots of console.logs().

Comment: I followed your outstanding (really superlative!)  instructions (see updated launch.json), and edited the extensions, and put all of this in the ws folder. I am Launching the DOM debugger, but it still shows a grey breakpoint. Can I show you the log? (windows 7, 64 bit). VScode 1.7.2 (but running node 7.2 on the computer)

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate it didn't work.  Sure, I'll take a look at your log.  One thing you can check for is Debugger.scriptParsed events in the debugger's detail log and confirm that your js files are mentioned (or throw a logger.log(script.url) in that method above).  I had an issue when I first setup a project where Chrome was combining my javascript files into a single eval (optimization maybe?) and the debugger skips those.  But after I added more code Chrome switched back to parsing whole files and the debugger starting working.

Comment: I added the a link to the log. I also tried adding about 100 lines of javascript to the index.js file. I don't see the parse message. I am also having issues with debugging with the built in debugger. I when I place the breakpoints in the onload="start()" method, see a large press CNTRL-P in the source tab. Not the source, and is not at a breakpoint.

Comment: I have switched to Electron, and I am much happier.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to debug with the follow configurations:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Node Debug",
        "type": "nwjs",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "/home/anne/Documents/nwjs/nw",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/build",
            "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
        ],
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/build",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "port": 9222
    }
]
```

}

Versions:

```
nwjs debbuger : 1.0.17
node :v10.11.0
react:16.4.1
```

I really hope this can help other guys!

[image]

(Folder structure to help on the context)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update for Craig answer.

Debugger for Chrome extension version 3.1.8 requires different change:
In `[extensions path]\.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-3.1.8/out/bundle.js` replace

```
exports.targetFilter = target => target && (!target.type || target.type === 'page');
```

with

```
exports.targetFilter = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hit breakpoints in the node code with the new default debugger by adding `--mixed-context` to the runtime args:

```
"runtimeArgs": [
   "${workspaceRoot}",
   "--mixed-context",
   "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
],
```

See [docs](https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/JavaScript%20Contexts%20in%20NW.js/#mixed-context-mode)